# Pop up on Mac from AVG

Tags: mac, macos, pop

I installed AVG antivirus then  deleted it using the AVG website.  I keep getting popups on my iMac using Yosemite 10.10 stating Problem Report for Loader Agent. The popup persists even though the program has been deleted properly. The path to the file is: `Library/Application Support/AVG/*/LoaderAgent.app./Contents/MacOS/`.  AVG support has not been helpful to delete the popup.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigations i found that LoaderAgent is part of the AVG LinkScanner installation. So download the [installer](https://share.avg.com/steam/PSP/avg_lsm_stf_all_90_867.dmg) and use the uninstaller in the dmg. It removes the LoaderAgent.app and supplemental files and folders.

**Just for record keeping, my earlier answer:**

> Which AVG Antivirus did you install? Did you get the installer package from a reliable source?
>
> The latest AVG Antivirus for Mac doesn't create a folder named AVG in /Library/Application Support/ - at least for me using the free installer and not subscribing to any additional services or installing AVG Cleaner or PrivacyFix. Instead the folder is named com.avg.Antivirus. Especially it doesn't contain a LoaderAgent.app in any of the subfolders. Moreover I can't uninstall it "using the AVG website".
>
> To get rid of the remnants of your AVG deinstallation, download and install ["LaunchControl"](http://www.soma-zone.com/download/files/LaunchControl_1.19.1.tar.bz2)
>
> Open the app and search for avg in Global Agents/Global Daemons.
>
> [image: launch]
>
> Uncheck all radio buttons to disable the jobs
>
> [image: launch2]
>
> Quit LaunchControl, go to /Library/LaunchAgents and /Library/LaunchAgents, check for plists containing avg and open Terminal.app
>
> Enter `sudo launchctl unload <-Drop the *.plist here` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to unload all related services. If the plist is a symbolic link or an alias right-click it and choose "Show Original" and use the original plist. You have to enter an admin password then.
>   Repeat that for every plist containing *.avg.
>
> Then enter `sudo rm <-Drop the *.plist here` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   Repeat that for every plist containing *.avg.
>
> Navigate to /Library/Application Support/ with
>   `cd /Library/Application\ Support` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> Then enter `sudo rm -dfR AVG` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> Restart your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall it with the uninstaller, or drag it to the trash?

> **To uninstall AVG Antivirus for Mac:**
>
> 1. Run the AVG AntiVirus for Mac.
> 2. Click the AVG AntiVirus Menu bar, and then click Uninstall AVG AntiVirus.
> 3. Click Uninstall AVG AntiVirus.
> 4. Follow the AVG AntiVirus Uninstaller to finish the uninstallation process.
>
>    Note: Please do not uninstall AVG AntiVirus by dragging it's icon into Trash, as this will not uninstall the application correctly. In such case, please install AVG AntiVirus again, and then follow the instructions above to uninstall the application.

Source - http://www.avg.com/gb-en/faq.num-5518